# Como fazer validação de senha em python:

Tags: python, while

Fiz um código para validar a senha com alguns requisitos:

```
print("Cadastre aqui sua senha com os seguintes criétios: \n"
      "         *Ao menos 8 digitos\n"
      "         *Ao menos uma letra MAIÚSCULA\n"
      "         *Ao menos um número\n"
      "         *Ao menos um caractere especial(!@#$%¨&*)\n")
senha = str(input("Digite sua senha : "))

#validação

while senha.islower():
        senha = input("A senha deve ter pelo menos um caractere MAIUSCULO: ")

while len(senha) < 7 :
    senha = input("A senha deve ter pelo menos 8 caracteres: ")

while senha.isalpha() :
    senha = input("Necessita de um numero: ")

while senha.isalnum() :
    senha = input("Necessita de um Caractere especial: ")
```

o problema é que ele faz uma validação por vez, gostaria que olhasse todas as situações..Como posso fazer isso ? Além do mais é importante que quando o usuário nao cumprir um requisito ele solite novamente a senha.

Answer (score -1):

Para validar uma senha com vários requisitos ao mesmo tempo, uma boa referencia é usar expressões regulares.

As expressões regulares é uma maneira de reproduzir padrões de texto em uma string.

Validar usando como  requisitos   **"** *ter pelo menos* **"**

- **8 dígitos**
- **1 letra maiúscula**
- **1 número**
- **1 caractere especial**

usando expressão regular  pode representa-los.

O `import re` é um [módulo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) do Python que representa  expressões regulares

```
import re

print("Cadastre aqui sua senha com os seguintes critérios: \n"
      "         *Ao menos 8 digitos\n"
      "         *Ao menos uma letra MAIÚSCULA\n"
      "         *Ao menos um número\n"
      "         *Ao menos um caractere especial(!@#$%¨&*)\n")
senha = input("Digite sua senha : ")
```

`re.search()` função que ira procurar por um padrão na string verificando se o padrão é correspondente. `and` é o operador lógico que combina duas expressões

```
(r'.{8,}, senha') and
(r'[A-Z]', senha) and
(r'\d', senha) and   
(r'[!@#$%¨&*]', senha)):
```

E para manter uma interatividade o `while not` pode ajudar nessa tarefa

`while not` é uma estrutura de controle de [fluxo](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter5_loops.html) que permitira que o loop seja chamado varias vezes enquanto a condição não for `True`

Essa é uma  implementação  usando expressões regulares :

```
import re

print("Cadastre aqui sua senha com os seguintes critérios: \n"
      "         *Ao menos 8 digitos\n"
      "         *Ao menos uma letra MAIÚSCULA\n"
      "         *Ao menos um número\n"
      "         *Ao menos um caractere especial(!@#$%¨&*)\n")
senha = input("Digite sua senha : ")

while not (re.search(r'.{8,}', senha) and   
           re.search(r'[A-Z]', senha) and 
           re.search(r'\d', senha) and   
           re.search(r'[!@#$%¨&*]', senha)):  
    senha = input("Use como base os critérios informado : ")

print("Senha cadastrada com sucesso!")
```

Answer (score -2):

Não pule os conceitos básicos, tenha calma e busque fazer as perguntas corretas.

[Tutoriais Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial) ...

```
while True:
    senha = str(input("Digite sua senha : "))
    if senha.islower():
        print("A senha deve ter pelo menos um caractere MAIUSCULO: ")
    elif len(senha) < 7 :
        print("A senha deve ter pelo menos 8 caracteres: ")
    elif senha.isalpha() :
        print("Necessita de um numero: ")
    elif senha.isalnum() :
        print("Necessita de um Caractere especial: ")
    else:
        break
```